# JSF conditional attribute on html5 tag

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

Hi i have an "fieldset" tag in my jsf page

now i need to conditional add an "disabled" attribute

i have a solution, but it is very ugly:

```
<h:outputText escape="false" value="&lt;fieldset disabled='disabled'&gt;" rendered="#{surveysHandler.surveyRunning}" />
<h:outputText escape="false" value="&lt;/fieldset&gt;" rendered="#{surveysHandler.surveyRunning}" />
```

is there a cool jsf 2.2 method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a cool new JSF 2.2 way to achieve this!

You can make the `fieldset` a JSF 2.2 passthrough element and pass it a map of attributes like this:

```
<fieldset jsf:id="fieldset">
    <f:passThroughAttributes value="#{customerBean.params}"/>
</fieldset>
```

The prefix `jsf` is for the new JSF 2.2 namespace `http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf`. If an HTML tag has any attribute in this namespace, JSF will convert it to a real JSF component in the component tree. Therefore it is possible to use `f:passThroughAttributes`to add attributes coming from a map in a managed bean.

The getter for the params property could look like this (you can add attributes based on any condition in the bean):

```
public Map<String, String> getParams() {
    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    if (disabled) {
        params.put("disabled", "disabled");
    }
    return params;
}
```

For further information about passthrough attributes and elements, have a look at my blogpost about [HTML5 friendly markup with JSF 2.2](http://jsflive.wordpress.com/2013/08/08/jsf22-html5).

Comment: I find the example rather confusing and I don't get it to work, as you mix the `f:passThroughAttribute` syntax with that used in the "Passthrough Elements" section from the page you linkedand so I end getting a "Tag Library supports namespace: http://java.sun.com/jsf/core, but no tag was defined for name: passThroughAttributes" exception.